# Android obtaining gridview similar to google play

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am looking to obtain a layout like this:

[image]

I am trying to create a gridview item like the one used here for 'albums', but i am trying for a simpler version with just an image on top and text below it. 
Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_card"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout></FrameLayout>
```

Howver, when i do this, i get an image in the centre with with white spaces all around it and no text displayed. 
What is the correct layout to be used to obtain a griditem like shown in the image
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/picture"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="testing" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Comment: ok. the text is visible now, but i am still getting a lot of white space around the image which keeps increasing as the size of the images increases unlike the compact layout in the image above. How do i resolve that?

Comment: Did you try with different images?

Comment: yes i did. I keep getting different amounts of white space depending on which image i choose.

Comment: any idea how to fix this?